# uniquely Identify list item generated by ngFor

Tags: angular

I created a list and sub list using dl, dt, dd and ngFor in my Angular project. To generate the list, I use an array in my component. I need to show and hide each sub list when clicking on the particular list item. But here, every item click show and hide every sub list. How can I solve this?

Code:

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AngularTest';
  arr = [
    {
        'id':1,'pid':0,'name':'Aaa','age':14
    },
    {
        'id':2,'pid':1,'name':'Bbb','age':14
    },
    {
        'id':3,'pid':1,'name':'Ccc','age':14
    },
    {
        'id':4,'pid':0,'name':'Ddd','age':14
    },
    {
        'id':5,'pid':4,'name':'Eee','age':14
    },
    {
        'id':6,'pid':4,'name':'Fff','age':14
    },
    {
        'id':7,'pid':2,'name':'Ggg','age':14
    },
    {
        'id':8,'pid':3,'name':'Hhh','age':14
    },
    {
        'id':9,'pid':0,'name':'Iii','age':14
    },
    {
        'id':10,'pid':0,'name':'Jjj','age':14
    },
  ];

show:boolean = false;

showme(){
    this.show = !this.show;
}

}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div>
    <dl *ngFor="let person of arr">
        <dt *ngIf="person.pid==0; then m"></dt>
        <ng-template #m>
            <dt (click)='showme()'>
                {{person.name}}
            </dt>
            <dl *ngFor="let child of arr">
                <dt *ngIf="child.pid==person.id; then s"></dt>
                <ng-template #s>
                    <dd *ngIf="show">
                        {{child.name}}
                    </dd>
                </ng-template>
            </dl>
        </ng-template>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: attach the `show` variable to your displayed items instead of having only one : `'id':10,'pid':0,'name':'Jjj','age':14, show: false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use index value to identify unique Element like this

```
<div>
    <dl *ngFor="let person of arr;let i= index">
        <dt *ngIf="person.pid==0; then m"></dt>
        <ng-template #m>
            <dt (click)='toggle[i]=!toggle[i]'>
                {{person.name}}
            </dt>
            <dl *ngFor="let child of arr">
                <dt *ngIf="child.pid==person.id; then s"></dt>
                <ng-template #s>
                    <dd *ngIf="toggle[i]">
                        {{child.name}}
                    </dd>
                </ng-template>
            </dl>
        </ng-template>
    </dl>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/unqiuediv

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the boolean value in each object of the array , rather than having a common one. Modify your elements with boolean value and **`disable/enable`** based on the click.

**example**

```
 {
   'id':1,'pid':0,'name':'Aaa','age':14,'show':false
 }
```

and the template will be,

```
<ng-template #m>
    <dt (click)='showMe(person)'>
```

and in component,

```
showMe(person:any){
   person.show = !person.show;
}
```

Comment: `(click)='person.show = !person.show'` would be shorter