# Angular 2 change ngFor items class knowing only it's index

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a lot of buttons in my `*ngFor`, and I want that when someone click's on a button - it becomes active(it gets active class).

What I've done :

**HTML :**

```
<button 
  [ngClass]="{'activeBtn': buttActive }" 
  (click)="addDistrict(item);changeActive(i)" 
  *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" 
  ion-button 
  #disable>
  {{item.name}}
</button>
```

**TS :** (changing all buttons class to active (i want to change only that one i clicked)

```
buttActive = false;
changeActive(i) {
  console.log(i);
  this.buttActive = !this.buttActive;
}
```

Comment: Only the one I clicked as in? should all the other buttons get rid of the active class?

Comment: If I click on the button - it should became active, others should stai normal unless you click on them.

Comment: Now I've done that if clicked on a button - all becomes active.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309397/uniquely-identify-list-item-generated-by-ngfor/52309555#52309555

Comment: @Angulandy2, I've updated my answer with a StackBlitz demo. Please have a look. Hope that fixes your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a `buttActive` property in the object and change it

```
button [ngClass]="{'activeBtn': item.buttActive }"  (click)="addDistrict(item);changeActive(item,i)"  
*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"     ion-button #disable>{{item.name}}</button>


 changeActive(item, i){
    console.log(i);
    item.buttActive = !item.buttActive;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you could also post how to delete active class of that item ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create a property on each item, then create a `lastClickedIndex` property in your Component class and set it with the index of the button that was clicked:

```
lastClickedIndex;
changeActive(i) {
  this.lastClickedIndex = i;
}
```

And in your template, check for the `lastClickedIndex` button based on `index` to apply the `activeBtn` class.

```
<button 
  *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" 
  [ngClass]="(lastClickedIndex == i) ? 'activeBtn': ''" 
  (click)="addDistrict(item);changeActive(i)" 
  ion-button 
  #disable>
  {{item.name}}
</button>
```

That way you won't have to create a property on each item object. This will also take care of removing the class from the previously selected button when some other button is clicked.

Here's a [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-buttons-styling) for your ref.